# Laptop hot, CPU intensice

Tags: performance

Laptop has been at around 70 degrees C for a while while idle compared to regular of around 50 (60 under load).

Load average is 3 compared to past of 1.2 to 1.5.

`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep MHz` returns 2900 consistently when in the past it would be as low as 1533.

What might be causing all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run top to see what process is using the most CPU resource

Comment: Nevermind. `htop` lists around 20 firefox processes each using 395MB of RES memory. At some time I downloaded "Folding at Home" and it is using 98% of my process. I don't know how to get rid of it or why I downloaded it.

Comment: Well, got rid of it. Load average rapidly dropping, temperature rapidly dropping, all that. Thanks.